# RSpec View testing: How to modify params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to test my views with RSpec. The particular view that is causing me troubles changes its appearance depending on a url parameter:

`link_to "sort>name", model_path(:sort_by => 'name')` which results in `http://mydomain/model?sort_by=name`

My view then uses this parameter like that:

```
<% if params[:sort_by] == 'name' %>
<div>Sorted by Name</div>
<% end %>
```

The RSpec looks like this:

```
it "should tell the user the attribute for sorting order" do
    #Problem: assign params[:sort_for] = 'name' 
    render "/groups/index.html.erb"
    response.should have_tag("div", "Sorted by Name")
end
```

I would like to test my view (without controller) in RSpec but I can't get this parameter into my `params` variable. I tried `assign` in all different flavours:

- `assign[:params] = {:sort_by => 'name'}`
- `assign[:params][:sort_by] = 'name'`
- ...

no success so far. Every idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Canonical answer:

To use params in views from within view specs, if your view has `params[:id]`, then somewhere in your spec do:

```
controller.extra_params = { id: widget.id }
```

Documentation: https://rspec.info/features/6-0/rspec-rails/view-specs/view-spec

However, it is also a good idea to not reference `params` in your views.

To get them out of your views you could use a helper, like this:

```
<div>Sorted by <%= sorted_by %></div>
```

And in one of your helper files

```
def sorted_by
    params[:sorted_by].capitalize
end
```

Unfortunately, you really shouldn't be referencing `params` in helpers either.  Don't reference what you don't own, ideally.

A better idea would be to use the [Presenter Pattern](https://oozou.com/blog/abstracting-ruby-on-rails-view-logic-with-presenters-51), and a good example of a tool for that is [ViewComponent](https://viewcomponent.org/).

Comment: This answer is decent from an informational perspective, but it doesn't answer the question.  There is a documented way to do this: `controller.extra_params = { id: widget.id }`
See: https://rspec.info/features/6-0/rspec-rails/view-specs/view-spec/ and my alternative answer.

Answer (score 38):

If its a controller test then it would be

```
controller.stub!(:params).and_return {}
```

If its a helper test then it would be:

```
helper.stub!(:params).and_return {}
```

And its a view test it would be:

```
view.stub!(:params).and_return {}
```

If you get warning like below.

```
Deprecation Warnings:

Using `stub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead. Called from /home/akbarbin/Documents/Office/projects/portfolio/spec/views/admin/waste_places/new.html.erb_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'.


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

1 deprecation warning total

Finished in 4.86 seconds (files took 4.72 seconds to load)
```

You can change it into

```
allow(view).to receive(:params).and_return({sort_by: 'name'})
```

Comment: I found this the helpful, but I used Rspec 3 syntax: `allow(view).to receive(:params).and_return({action: 'index'})`

Answer (score 5):

The easy way is to just do this:

```
helper.params = {:foo => '1', :bar => '2'}
```

But in general it's better to be more integration-y and not "stub" values when it's feasible. So I prefer to use controller tests with **integrate_views**. Then you can specify your params to the **get**, and test that the entire flow works, from sending params to the controller, to having them processed by the controller, and finally to rendering.

I also generally prefer to pull out view logic into helpers, which can be easier to test.

For instance, say I have a helper called **selection_list**, which returns a Hash whose "selected_preset" key relies on **params[:selected_preset]**, and defaults to 42 if an empty value is specified for the param.

Here's a controller test where we've called **integrate_views** (you could of course do the same thing with an actual view test, if you're into that).

```
describe '#show' do
  describe 'selected_preset' do
    it 'should default to 42 if no value was entered' do
      get :show, :params => {:selected_preset => ''}
      response.template.selection_list[:selected_preset].should == 42
```

This integration test will alert me if some part of this functionality breaks. But I also would ideally like to have some *unit* tests to help me *pinpoint* that breakage.

I'll start by having the helper use an instance variable instead of directly accessing params. I'll change the above code by adding a single line directly below the get, as follows:

```
describe '#show' do
  describe 'selected_preset' do
    it 'should default to 42 if no value was entered' do
      get :show, :params => {:selected_preset => ''}
      assigns[:selected_preset].should == 42 # check instance variable is set
      response.template.selection_list[:selected_preset].should == 42
```

Now I also can easily perform a helper unit test:

```
describe MyHelper do
  describe '#selection_list' do
    it 'should include the selected preset' do
      assigns[:selected_preset] = 3
      helper.selection_list[:selected_preset].should == 3
```

Comment: It seems that "integrate_views" is now deprecated in favor of "render_views". https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views

Comment: when testing helper specs `helper.params.merge!(:foo => '1', :bar => '2')` works

Answer (score 3):

Another method of setting view params:

```
controller.request.path_parameters[:some_param] = 'a value'
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good, and it *is* bad to use params in views... but there is (now) a documented way to do this, and as such the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question.

```
controller.extra_params = { id: widget.id }
```

See: https://rspec.info/features/6-0/rspec-rails/view-specs/view-spec/